# How to make a website have an icon when placed on an Android home screen?

Tags: html, favicon, android

How can I make **Dance Culture** have an **icon** on the **Android wallpaper** like it has with **WolframAlpha**. See screenshot below.

I've found **favicon** but can't tell what's different in the **html source code** to **enable** **WolframAlpha** to have it whilst **Dance Culture** has a **generic icon**.

Please see source code:

[Dance Culture](https://danceculture.com.au/):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://danceculture.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/favicon.ico">
```

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href=/static/favicon.ico>
```

[image: website icon on Android wallpaper]

Comment: See also: [Favicon Compatible Resolutions and File Size for various Devices](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/45435/favicon-compatible-resolutions-and-file-size-for-various-devices)

Comment: [Favicon checker](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker) This website will reveal what formats your setup supports. You can also generate all of the icon content for free.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a 158 x 158 image to be used as an icon.
2. Save your creation as a .png file to a location on your server.
3. Note down the path e.g `https://example.com/images/apple-touch-icon.png`.
4. Now you just need to add a simple little line of code to the index.php of your site to let phones know that you want it to use your icon whenever someone bookmarks your site or saves your site to their Home screen. This is the code:

   ```
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/https://example.com/images/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
   ```

   You are going to place this code just above the `</head>` tag on your website's main page.

   Remember to change out the path to the image path you wrote down in the step above.

Comment: I note there's apple in the rel section. Is this for apple only then? I want it to support android.

Comment: @DarrynBrisdaz: I believe Android does pick up on Apple touch icons.  That said, this is the quick-and dirty approach to creating app icons.

Comment: Adding to this thread,
Steps 1, 2 and 3 was the same.
I used below HTML5 Tag in body section `<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="152x152" href="images/The_Image.png"/>`
I tried in Samsumg Tab and the below steps worked for me.